# Windows mobile native exception C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, native

I have a windows mobile solution which contains two projects. One written in C# and another in C++ (unmaneged code that compiles into a dll). 
The part written in C# invokes some C++ functions from dll to connect to a server.

If I open my application and I connect to the server everything works ok. If I minimize it , or if I open another windows mobile application over my application and try again to connect to the server it fails with a native exception code. (Exception code: 0xc000001d.)

Any idea what happens to my native code when I minimize my application? Why it doesn't work anymore? The error appears both on emulator and target device.
I use Windows 6.1 Professional and CF 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Exception code 0xc000001d is **STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION**. I.e. the code tried to run an instruction which doesn't belong to the processor's instruction set.

This could be because of many reasons:

- stack corruption (because of overflow in arrays)
- corrupted dll/binary

See the code that handles window state changes (minimize/maximize/restore). See if any calls to functions like `memcpy`, `strcpy`, etc. are ajar. These are unsafe functions for which [secure equivalents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wes2t00f%28VS.80%29.aspx) are available with a `_s` suffix. Check if some raw pointer/array manipulation writes beyond it's boundary to cause a [stack corruption](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Basics/debugging_software_crashes.htm). Also check the integrity of the dll, if you're sure it's because of the code in the dll.

**Edit:**

If you've the DLL's source with you, build it with the map file generation ON (Linker Param: `/MAPINFO:EXPORTS`). And when the exception is thrown, usually you'll get a address inside the binary where the crash happens; this can be looked-up in the map file, to know the exact function where it crashes (it it's a stack corruption the exact function will only help a little, but it'll give the corruption's vicinity). See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx) for further details.